# JS regex remove typecasts

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all type casts from a js file.

The current (not-working) regex I have is:

```
/(?!new\s+&?!function\s+)\w+\((.+)\)/gi
```

Basically I want anything like Class(var) but not `new Class(arg)` or `function Func(arg)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 s = "Basically I want anything like Class(var) but not new Class(arg) or function Func(arg)"

re = /(?:(?!new|function)\b\S+|^|[^\w\s])\s*\b([A-Z]\w*\s*\(.*?\))/g

for (var match; (match = re.exec(s));) { alert(match[1]); }
```

produces

```
 Class(var)
```

but will only match correctly if there are no nested parentheses in the actual parameter list.  To generally match a function call is not possible using regular expressions since regular grammars can't handled nested parenthetical groups.

Comment: I gave this the check because I think your answer answers the question I put (quite cleverly in fact), but after putting this in my script, it started changing other things that I hadn't mentioned.

Comment: @Jackson, have you looked into proper JavaScript parsers that would allow you to parse your script, walk the resulting parse tree, modify it, and then render it out?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511556/javascript-parser-for-java discussed this recently, and if you're not fluent in java, there are other discussion on SO for python and other languages.  I believe JSLint is built around a JS parser.