# Parsing HTML page containing JS in Java

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am trying to parse a web page, which contains some JS. Till now I am using `Jsoup` to parse html in Java, which is working as expected. But I am unable to parse the JavaScript. Below is the snippet of the HTML page-

```default-markup
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var element = document.createElement("input"); 
element.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
element.setAttribute("value", "");
element.setAttribute("name", "AzPwXPs");
element.setAttribute("id", "AzPwXPs");
var foo = document.getElementById("dnipb"); 
foo.appendChild(element);
var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
element1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
element1.setAttribute("value", "6D6AB8AECC9B28235F1DE39D879537E1");
element1.setAttribute("name", "ZLZWNK");
element1.setAttribute("id", "ZLZWNK");
foo.appendChild(element1);
</script>
```

I want to read both the values with their `name`/`id`. So that after parsing I can get following results-

```
AzPwXPs=
ZLZWNK=6D6AB8AECC9B28235F1DE39D879537E1
```

How to parse in this situation?

Comment: Jsoup only parse HTML. It cannot parse or run JS.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Ya, I know that. That is why I am stuck in between... :( But there must some other way around

Comment: Run it through a JS parser? Or get a JS engine? (I actually also have the same problem on a side project, but I never got my hand around it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium's Webdriver is fantastic:  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

See this answer for an example of what you are trying to do:
[Using Selenium Web Driver to retrieve value of a HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input)

Comment: What you mean by  jQuery is being used? Can you explain me a little bit more please?

Comment: the javascript `return $('#AzPwXPs')[0]` uses a jquery selector ( $('#AzPwXPs')) to find the element.

Comment: So, finally in my java parser project there will be `Selenium's Webdriver` with `jquery`. Is it?

Comment: no, you don't need to use jquery - i'm just going to link to an answer that shows you a better example

Answer (score 6):

I have stumbled upon this question few times when searching for the solution to parse pages with JavaScript but the solution provided is not perfect. I have found pure Java solution to the problem by using [JBrowserDriver](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver) and [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse JavaScript manipulated page.

Simple example:

```
    // JBrowserDriver part
    JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings
            .builder().
            timezone(Timezone.EUROPE_ATHENS).build());
    driver.get(FETCH_URL);
    String loadedPage = driver.getPageSource();

    // JSoup parsing part
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(loadedPage);
    Elements elements = document.select("#nav-console span.data");

    log.info("Found element count: {}", elements.size());

    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I already had the same situation to find url's in css files.

Put the javascript in a string and a apply Regular expressions

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("url\\(\\s*(['" + '"' + "]?+)(.*?)\\1\\s*\\)"); //expression
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
String urlFound = m.group(); 
}
```

Regards,
Hugo Pedrosa

Comment: Although I got the logic but how this can be modified to serve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using query library. Its much more easier with it.

Comment: Can you please suggest any one of them? Is it available in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've got the text content of the `<script>` element from JSoup, you can parse the JS using the [Caja JS parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6512117/20394) and then walk the parse tree to find what you're looking for.

Comment: How to get `<script>` element from JSoup?

Comment: @Ravi, If you're doing something like `Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...)`, then `doc.getElementsByTag("script").first()` should get you the first script in the page.