# How parse site after loading javascripts with Java

Tags: javascript, java, parsing

Hello i need get video url from site with parsing from json. But i can't get video with tag because it creting with javascript.

```
<script>var player = jwplayer('player-embed');      
player.setup({"file": "http://dushanbe.mix.tj/video/2/45/5bafae1306081.mp4", "image": "/img/b/7/42/113989.jpg", "aspectratio": "16:9", "autostart": false, "controls": true, "displaydescription": false, "displaytitle": false, "flashplayer": "/player/jwplayer-7.8.7/jwplayer.flash.swf", "key": "n+94L7vjfQNGEin57ap3glk3iRNum2o7AeOIWw==", "mute": false, "ph": 1, "pid": "mS6Np6yN", "preload": "auto", "primary": "html5",  "repeat": false, "stagevideo": false, "stretching": "uniform", "width": "100%"});</script>
```

How parse site after loading javascripts on Java ?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316691/parsing-html-page-containing-js-in-java