# Parse JavaScript with Java

Tags: javascript, java, parsing

In a `HTML` page, i want to pick the value of a `javascript` variable. Below is the snippet of HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-MOON-EXPIRED', "1445350653");
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-MOON-TOKEN', "10dafe974cc156d2d3b7fd9bb1e4e3ed");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

My aim is to read the value of variable `X-MOON-EXPIRED` and `X-MOON-TOKEN` from this page using `Java`. Thanks.

Comment: You *might* be able to get by here with a regex or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript parser for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511556/javascript-parser-for-java)

Comment: Does the page with the javascript on it belong to you, or are you scraping it off someone else's page?

Comment: Based on the answer below, it appears that the question is NOT UNCLEAR.   Based on that, I think this "hold" is unreasonable.  Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("X-MOON-EXPIRED', \"([^\"]*)\"");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("X-MOON-TOKEN', \"([^\"]*)\"");
String html = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> $(function() {   $.ajaxSetup({     beforeSend: function(xhr) {       xhr.setRequestHeader('X-MOON-EXPIRED', \"1445350653\");       xhr.setRequestHeader('X-MOON-TOKEN', \"10dafe974cc156d2d3b7fd9bb1e4e3ed\");     }   }); }); </script>";
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(html);
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(html);
if (!m1.find() || !m2.find()) {
    throw new Exception("Didn't match");
}
System.out.println(String.format("X-MOON-EXPIRED=%s, X-MOON-TOKEN=%s", m1.group(1), m2.group(1)));
```

Prints:

```
X-MOON-EXPIRED=1445350653 X-MOON-TOKEN=10dafe974cc156d2d3b7fd9bb1e4e3ed
```