# Parsing Javascript functions from a Javascript source text

Tags: java, parsing

I've been looking for a *Javascript parser* on Java that can capture and list all Javascript functions, for example

```
function beforeSave('Test', request, response) {
    response.body = entity.foo;
    if (request.query.isExist('Test', 'foo', entity.foo)) {
        response.error();
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
}

function afterSave('Test', request, response) {
    response.body = 'done';
    response.success();
}
```

Is there a Javascript parser library for Java that would be able to list all Functions from a given source text as well as get the function bodies as needed.

Comment: Java is not java script.

Comment: Ecmascript parser for Java

Answer (score 0):

I believe java.util.regex is the right tool for the job.

With that you can search for keywords in strings. Example for getting the body of the function:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("function', \"([^\"]*)\"");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(String);
System.out.println(String.format("function=%s",m1.group(1)));
```

To see more about this go to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239311/parse-javascript-with-java).

I´m not a Java-expert by any means so check out the other question and the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) of the library for more information.