# Regular expression with an exception

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way to add a regex exception to a regular expression?

Example:

```
(regular expression/regular expression to ignore)
```

I have the following regular expression:

```
\W
```

But would like for it to ignore strings inside quotation marks (Regex i will use for this is: `"(.*?)"`). But i don't know how to add an exception to the `\W` regex.

I want something like this:

```
\W(ignore->"(.*?)")
```

Any ideas? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, in PCRE, it is a piece of cake: `"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\W`. What is your regex flavor?

Comment: I'm trying to implement this in JavaScript

Comment: Ok, so what is your code? What is your intention: extract, replace, remove, split? Show some real life test case.

Comment: I was trying to separate an input code (Java class in the form of a .txt) into an array of "tokens". I used the \W to separate the code into multiple lines. But with this i ran to the issue of having strings being split as well. Using an exception in the \W for strings inside quotes would fix this. :)

Comment: Please just find the dedicated language parser. A single splitting regex won't help you parse an arbitrary Java file correctly.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511556/javascript-parser-for-java) should help, I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Your question asks about `\W` (non-word characters), but perhaps you meant to split on those.  It seems you meant to match those, so I changed the upper-case `\W` to lower case `\w` in my answer.

You might be looking for something like this: `(?:"[^"]*?"|\w)+`

The idea is to treat quoted substrings differently.  Here is how it works:

- One or more of the contents: **`(?:`** "[^"]*?"|\w **`)+`** where the contents are...
- Either a quoted string **`[^"]*?"`** or word character **`\w`**
- The quoted string is **`[^"]*?"`** is a `"` followed by as few as possible non-quote characters **`[^"]*?`**, followed by the closing `"`.

Comment: This `(?:"[^"]*?"|\w)+` is not going to help in the end, since a mere `String str = "with \"quotes\" inside";` line will break it.

Comment: Yes, this example only works for simple strings.  If your source file includes things like `$"{("h")}"` or `@">""<"` it would likely need a language parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this using a single regex, but you can do it in 2 steps. (i) Replace the exception with an empty string; (ii) Search in the new string.

```js
let text = `Hey "aaa bbbb &&&&&&" !@# "hahaha 123 %%%" !!!`;

let newText = text.replace(/"(.*?)"/g,"");

console.log(newText);

let matches = newText.match(/\W/g);

console.log(matches);
```